# Does psql print command results to standard error?

Tags: errors, psql, copy, redshift

I am running COPY command through psql 9.1.15 as a cronjob to append data in csv file to table1:

```
psql -q -h $DB_HOST -d $DB_NAME -p $DB_PORT -U $DB_USER <<EOF
copy table1
from '${BUCKET}/${DATA_FILE}' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ID;aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_KEY' 
csv 
EOF
```

I am redirecting stdout but not stderr. The idea is that if there is an error, it will be passed to cron and it will send me email.

However, I am getting from psql this stuff printed to stderr:

```
INFO:  Load into table 'table1' completed, 342 record(s) loaded successfully.
```

The psql command does return 0 as exit code, so there are no errors.

The question is, does psql print this stuff to stderr or does the database server (Amazon Redshift) pass this message to psql marked as error? I have a hunch that this is psql's fault, based on [this post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/199812312018.PAA16610@candle.pha.pa.us).

Why would you print successful message as error anyway?

Comment: I suggest you take up this discussion with Bruce, who was asking for input.

Comment: Should I contact him even though the post is from 1998?

Comment: If there's no other way to get psql non-data output to stderr and thus to cron emails.